# I want to print a random sentecnce from my list every time i type x in input

Tags: python, string, list, random

```
import random
words = ["tree", "human", "city", "night", 
"falcon", "last", "first", "fruit", "animals", 
"often", "maybe", "through", "work", 
"good","random", "white"]
while True:
    sentence = input("print x: ")
    random_sentence = random.choice(words)
    print(random_sentence)

# i want it to be random sentence like this:
city last human fruit white animals often tree work through good random maybe falcon night first
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  You are not using `sentence`, a variable that you have created. Also, how long you want your sentence to be, i.e. how many words you want to get from the list?

Comment: Information on this page may help you: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/randomly-select-n-elements-from-list-in-python/

Comment: What is it supposed to do when you type something other than `x` in the the input? It's not clear if you are asking about building the random sentence or reacting to user input.

Comment: I just wrote x because it's close to my hand and I don't put my focus on this thing, and input I put it so I don't repeat it just whenever I write something I get a sentence, I want to make a random sentence of the words on the list.

Answer (score 0):

If I get it correctly, you want to have random sentences not just words each time you press enter for the input:

Here, I have considered a valid sentence somewhere between 15 to 30 words, and I create the sentences with random sizes (between 15 to 30) by calling the random choice method.

```
import random
words = ["tree", "human", "city", "night", 
"falcon", "last", "first", "fruit", "animals", 
"often", "maybe", "through", "work", 
"good","random", "white"]
while True:
    sentence = input("print x: ")
    random_sentence = ' '.join([random.choice(words) for i in range(random.randint(15,30))])
    print(random_sentence)


# example: 
#print x: >? 
#night often maybe often through night last through work night last often through random tree through falcon tree often human maybe falcon city white animals white human tree through
```